# Efficient Format for storing a range of values in database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am questioning the very orthodox method of storing(at least in my zone) the range of values in db in a format (i.e. **0:1:20;1:7:40**). 
This rule can mean,

- from 0 to 1 day I am gonna charge 20
- from 1 to 7 days I am gonna charge 40

---

Now, I am a believer of change and therefore would like to know if there is some other way to store such data in database which would give me flexibility in coding it as well as would require less space than the JSON format.

Comment: Use `from` and `to` columns

Comment: what means *"less space than the JSON format"*?

Comment: @NinaScholz like in JSON we would write the same thing as, { DayRange : 0-1, Charge : 20 }

Comment: @SagarGautam I don't think that's the solution, because for a single item in table i will have to make 2 entries according to your "solution". i.e. one row will be for 0 to 1 and another rule for 1 to 7

Comment: i would use `{ from: 0, to: 1, charge: 20 }`, so not further conversion is necessary.

Comment: @NinaScholz exactly, these words(from, to, charge) will increase the load as the entries get large.

Comment: then why not use the proposed string `'0:1:20'`?

Comment: that's a solution, but i wanted some other efficient innovative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have ranges which are consecutive, you could omit start value (if it is always zero) and use just the length of the range.

```
1|20     first range is starting with zero and ending on starting + length
6|40     second range starting with end of the last range
```